# Simplify: $\ln(x^2 − 4)− \ln(x − 2)− \ln 2$

Tags: calculus

Simplify:

$$\ln(x^2 − 4)− \ln(x − 2)− \ln2$$

$$\ln\dfrac{x^2 − 4}{x − 2}− \ln2$$

$$\ln(x + 2)− \ln2$$

$$\ln(x + 2)/2$$

I got this far, is there any other way to simplify it, or do I stop here?

Comment: That looks good.  I don't see how it could be simplified any further.

Comment: okay thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful with your parenthesis and your assumptions on $x$. As long as $x \neq 2$ we indeed have

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\ln(x^2 + 4) - \ln(x-2) - \ln(2) & = & \ln\left( \frac{x^2 - 4}{x-2} \right) - \ln(2) \\
& = & \ln (x+2) - \ln(2) \text{ as long as } x \neq 2\\
& = & \ln \left( \frac{x+2}{2} \right) \text{ note the parenthesis here} \\
& = & \ln ( x/2 + 1) \text{ possible simplication}
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Hope this helps!

Comment: That makes sense! Thank you